# Excel To PPT VBA Coding

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

The code runs without fault on a clear blank PowerPoint slide, but when i try Ind add multiple images from excel to PPT onto the same slide it loses its set positioning and formatting and goes to full scale on image 2,3 etc. and unable to identify the course.

Please find the code below which is used to run the script

```
enter code here
```

````
'app
'  pre
'   slide
'    shapes
'     text frame
'      text

Sub ExporttoPPT()
```
Dim ppt_app As New PowerPoint.Application
Dim pre As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim slde As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim rng As Range

Dim vSheet$
Dim vRange$
Dim vWidth As Double
Dim vHeight As Double
Dim vTop As Double
Dim vLeft As Double
Dim vSlide_No As Long
Dim expRng As Range


Dim adminSh As Worksheet
Dim cofigRng As Range
Dim xlfile$
Dim pptfile$


Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set adminSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Admin")
Set cofigRng = adminSh.Range("Rng_sheets")

xlfile = adminSh.[excelPth]
pptfile = adminSh.[pptPth]

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(xlfile, False, True)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set pre = ppt_app.Presentations.Open(pptfile)


For Each rng In cofigRng
   
   '----------------- set VARIABLES
   With adminSh
      vSheet$ = .Cells(rng.Row, 4).Value
      vRange$ = .Cells(rng.Row, 5).Value
      vWidth = .Cells(rng.Row, 6).Value
      vHeight = .Cells(rng.Row, 7).Value
      vTop = .Cells(rng.Row, 8).Value
      vLeft = .Cells(rng.Row, 9).Value
      vSlide_No = .Cells(rng.Row, 10).Value
      
      
      End With
   
   
   '----------------- EXPORT TO PPT
   
            wb.Activate
            Sheets(vSheet$).Activate
            Set expRng = Sheets(vSheet$).Range(vRange$)
            expRng.Copy
'            Stop
            
            pre.Application.Activate
            Set slde = pre.Slides(vSlide_No)
            
            'Application.ActiveWindow.Panes(vSlide_No).Activate
            slde.Select
            slde.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteBitmap 'ppPasteSecial' ppPasteBitmap
            Set shp = slde.Shapes(1)
            
                        
            With shp
               
               .Top = vTop
               .Left = vLeft
               .Width = vWidth
               .Height = vHeight
               
            End With
            
            
            Set shp = Nothing
            Set slde = Nothing
            Set expRng = Nothing
   
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Set expRng = Nothing
Next rng

'pre.Save
'pre.Close

Set pre = Nothing
Set ppt_app = Nothing

wb.Close False
Set wb = Nothing

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub``
````

Comment: `The code runs without fault` - what code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: OK, please add the code to your question instead, impossible/difficult to help you otherwise.

Comment: Code added first time posting on here so had to work out how to post the code

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you use always the very first shape when you set the position properties: You write `Set shp = slde.Shapes(1)`.

One solution is to use the last shape instead (new created shapes are put at the end of the collection):

```
slde.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteBitmap 
Set shp = slde.Shapes(slde.shapes.count)
```

Or you use the return value of `PasteSpecial`. However, the return value is a `ShapeRange` (a group of shapes). As in your case the group contains only one shape, you can use

```
Set shp = slde.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteBitmap)(1)
```